# loadByCode Newsletter template in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, newsletter

Is there a Magento 2 function like loadByCode for admin created Newsletter templates?

If not, how are you supposed to retrieve newsletter created in admin?

Answer (score 0):

This method is not available. So try following way:

Inject using DI:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\TemplateFactory $newsletterFactory
) {
    $this->newsletterFactory = $newsletterFactory;
}
```

Now use following way:

```
$template_code = 'abc';
$newsletter = $this->newsletterFactory->create()->load($template_code, 'template_code');
print_r($newsletter->getData());
```

***Another Way***

Inject using DI:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Template\CollectionFactory $newsletterCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->newsletterCollectionFactory = $newsletterCollectionFactory;

}
```

Now use following way:

```
$template_code = 'abc';
$newsletterCollection = $this->newsletterCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('template_code', $template_code);
foreach ($newsletterCollection as $newsletter) {
    print_r($newsletter->getData());
}
```

[Update]

**how do you actually send the newsletter template after loading it?**

```
$template_code = 'abc';
$newsletter = $this->newsletterFactory->create()->load($template_code, 'template_code');

$this->transportBuilder->setTemplateData(
    [
        'template_subject' => $newsletter->getTemplateSubject(),
        'template_text' => $this->getTemplateText(),
        'template_styles' => $this->getTemplateStyles(),
        'template_filter' => $this->templateFilter,
        'template_type' => 2, // 2 for html
    ]
);

/* Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory*/
$collection = $this->subscriberCollectionFactory->create()->useOnlyUnsent()->showCustomerInfo()->setPageSize(
    20
)->setCurPage(
    1
)->load();

/** @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $item */
foreach ($collection->getItems() as $item) {
    $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateOptions(
        ['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $item->getStoreId()]
    )->setTemplateVars(
        ['subscriber' => $item]
    )->setFrom(
        ['name' => 'sent from name', 'email' => 'sentfrom@mail.com']
    )->addTo(
        $item->getSubscriberEmail(),
        $item->getSubscriberFullName()
    )->getTransport();

    try {
        $transport->sendMessage();
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException $e) {

    }
}
```

[See sample code, how default code send email](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php#L198)

Comment: How do you set the $newletter object to send the email?

  $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('sendfriend_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
            //->setTemplateVars($emailTempVariables)
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($email, $name)
            ->setReplyTo($senderEmail)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();

Comment: Which email you set $newletter object?

Comment: I meant after you get the $newsletter from the collection in your example, how do you send it?

Comment: So you want to fetch all template and send to, right?

Comment: Right, how do you actually send the newsletter template after loading it?

Comment: Check updated answer